# Simple Python venv manager with different py versions?

Tags: python, virtualenv

To be honest, up until recently I was hoping to avoid everything related to vurtualenvs. Yep, very naïve.

All of the code I write using python is to be deployed using containers, where "one container - one app" is totally true for now. And also number of CLIs being distributed also to my coworkers as wheels.

What I came up with is two "global" environments living in my homedir:

- "default" virtual env with python 3.10 and some general packages installed. Using this venv I develop current versions of my applications and do my regular job. It is sourced automatically in `.bashrc`.
- Virtual env with python 3.9. This is used to support legacy versions of/not yet updated applications in case if something should be done to them.

And also for some of the projects there are dedicated virtual envs living in a project folder needed only for this particular project, python version there may vary from 3.7 to 3.10.

As a consequence, I have to change current environment by manually sourcing the right `activate` script several times a day, and this isn't funny.

After some research on the topic, I found things like `virtualenvwrapper`, `Pipenv` and `Poetry`, but none of them seem to meet all my needs: "global" env to use across multiple projects and outside projects (because of CLIs); ability to create env with given python version; easy switch between virtual envs.

Is there any solution for this?

### UPD: Some illustrations

Next virtual environments were created inside `~/pyenv/`:

```
$ virtualenv -p /usr/local/bin/python3.9 default3.9
$ virtualenv -p /usr/local/bin/python3.10 default3.10
```

Next, `.bashrc` was updated to do `source ~/pyenv/default3.10/bin/activate`.

Now, for the vast majority of tasks it is enough: everything needed for day-to-day job is installed in `default3.10` venv.

In case I need to switch to python3.9 the following is required:

```
$ deactivate
$ source ~/pyenv/default3.9/bin/activate
```

And if then I need to work on some project with its own venv, inside project folder I have to do:

```
$ deactivate
$ source env/bin/activate
```

Too many manual inputs. At minimal, I'd like to do something like `$ workon default3.9` no matter of the current directory I'm in, and it should activate `default3.9` venv correctly if no venv is active right now or if any venv if already active.
The same should work inside project folder: `$ workon <local_venv_name>` to switch to the venv living in current project folder.
And something like `venv create <enterpreter path/py version>` to create new "global" or "local" (in current folder only) venv, and `venv list` to get the list of available "global" and "local" environments.

Comment: for pipenv use `pipenv install --system` to install global dependencies in your virtual environment.

Comment: As I see in the docs, pipenv main ideology is that every project is a separate environment, which is not the case. Environment could be local for the project, but might be global for everything. Updated the question to better illustrate what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 0):

to use the global environment inside the project's local virtual environment.
set

```
include-system-site-packages = true
```

in `pyvenv.cfg` file located in .venv (virtual environment installation directory) directory of each project.